# Coerce the Postman Cli to yield the response payload after a collection request?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

The postman cli does yield this information after a collection request, but as of now I must parse it:

```
  ┌ ↓ application/json ★ text ★ json ★ utf8 ★ 74B
  │ {"error":"yak fur overgrowth","error_description":"yak fur obscures the horizon and the stars"}
  └
```

The JSON might always be one line or it could be many lines; it might wind up being easy or hard, but I'd prefer not to find out.

Is there a way to coerce `postman` to deliver its payload in plain JSON? My current command looks like:

```
postman collection run --verbose --env-var foo=bar <my-collection-id> -e <my-env-id> -i <my-request-id>
```